# iOS app crash with UICheckBox, drawLayer:inContext

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, crash, crashlytics

I recently published an iOS app, the app has around 1000 downloads now and I just had my first crash (I use Firebase Crashlytics).

I'm not sure I understand correctly this crash report, here is a screenshot : (iPhone Xr iOS 13.1.3, the (Manquant) in the screenshot means (Missing))
[image]

Here is my code in UICheckBox.swift line 16 : (I use UICheckBox_swift library)

[image]

Any idea how I can protect my app from this crash event ? Is this a system bug that I can't do anything about ?

Thanks

edit: Here is my FDColors class :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
self.layer.borderColor = (FDColors.gray707070).cgColor
```

and make sure `FDColors.gray707070` is UIColor

Comment: Thanks but could you explain me a bit more about your fix ? I don't understand what it could possibly change to add ( ) ?

Comment: I added the code of my FDColors class (screenshot) at bottom of my original post. Problem is I can't make it crash on purpose, it happened only one time on almost 1k downloads so I hope/guess this is just an iOS bug ?